# Cucumber : How to read examples from external excel file for Scenarios Outline

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

My requirement is to read examples from external excel file rather than hard code it into feature file. I have more than 100 examples which is difficult to maintain in feature file. Can you please help me on this.

Here is my scenario -

```
Scenario Outline: Browser Test

    When I visit the URL <base>/<page>/<ordNumber>/<custName>
    Then the browser contains test <custNumber>

    Examples: 
     | base                         | page   | ordNumber | custName |
     | http://www.stackoverflow.com | orders | 123       | John     |
     | http://www.stackoverflow.com | orders | 456       | Mike     |
     | http://www.stackoverflow.com | orders | 789       | Tom      |
```

I want to create an excel file with examples data and load it during runtime

**examples.xls**

```
 | base                         | page   | ordNumber | custName |
 | http://www.stackoverflow.com | orders | 123       | John     |
 | http://www.stackoverflow.com | orders | 456       | Mike     |
 | http://www.stackoverflow.com | orders | 789       | Tom      |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is supported using [gherkin with QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html). QAF support different external [data providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) including json, xml, csv, excel and DB. It also supports [multiple bdd syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html).

Using Gherkin or BDD2 with QAF below is the example:

```
Scenario Outline: Browser Test

    When I visit the URL <base>/<page>/<ordNumber>/<custName>
    Then the browser contains test <custNumber>

    Examples: {'datafile': 'resources/testdata/examples.xls'}
```

There are lots of other features as well for resource management, execution configuration, driver management and parallel execution.

Comment: any idea if we can use similar to this in Testcafe framework (Selenium JavaScript)

Comment: not in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would opt for generating the feature files based on a **template** and the use of a **template engine** (like Velocity).

For integration with Excel, you can use the **POI** library the read properly your *.xls file(s).

Then run the generated feature file(s) like you would with "hard-coded" ones.

Hope this helps !

Comment: What if the cells contain special characters e.g. "newline", how to put that inside the feature file?

Comment: You can replace actual characters by there extended version (like `\n` for *new line*), but for long multiline text blocs, cells are not the best fit, but **DocString** may be.