# How can I continue to run other steps when there is a failure using Serenity?

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I apologize for my bad English. I use google translate to post this question. I also searched many of my problems on the internet that did not resolve mine.

My problem is as follows: 
I have an excel file that allows the manual to import data. Each row in this excel file I use to create a new data (eg it looks like an account). It is not difficult.
Since each row corresponds to a different data to create a new data, be sure to use a loop to get the data inside the file. For example as follows:

**| Name | Email     | Tel    | .... | Result |** 
| A    | abc@email | 123456 | .... | accA   | 
| B    | abc@email | 123456 | .... | accB   |

Result column is generated based on the data of the other columns. 
I don't use the Scenario Template because there are many fields. And using excel to make the manual easier to edit and read. 
So I use the loop to **repeat the step** can mine the number of rows of data from excel files.

My code:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Before
    public void set_the_stage() {
        OnStage.setTheStage(new OnlineCast());
    }

    @Given("{word} access Google")
    public void accessGoogle(String actor) {
        theActorCalled(actor).attemptsTo(Open.url("https://google.com"));
    }

    @When("Input {word}")
    public void inputSearch(String value) {
        Target input_search = Target.the("Input Search").locatedBy("//input[@title='Tìm kiếm']");
        Target click_search = Target.the("Click Search").locatedBy("//*[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//*[ @value='Tìm với Google'] ");

        theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(WaitUntil.the(input_search, WebElementStateMatchers.isVisible()));
        theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Enter.theValue(value).into(input_search));
        // Failure step
        theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(WaitUntil.the(click_search, WebElementStateMatchers.isVisible()), Click.on(click_search));
    }

    @Then("Search successfully")
    public void searchSucess() {
        Target stackOverflow = Target.the("Stack Overflow").locatedBy("//*[contains(text(),'Stack Overflow')]");
        theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Ensure.that(stackOverflow).isDisplayed());
    }

    @When("Read excel")
    public void readExcel() {
        int number = 5; // the number of records in the excel file

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Start Try: " + i);
                accessGoogle("Minato");
                inputSearch("stackoverflow.com");
                searchSucess();
                System.out.println("End Try: " + i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Catch: " + i);
                ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.getDriver().quit();
                ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.initialize();
                set_the_stage();
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*feature file*

```
@feature=searchGoogle
Feature: A description

  @testSearch
  Scenario: A scenario
    When Read excel
```

In automation, every time there is a failure it throws an exception why the failure happens, and it stops the program.
With original selenium, to continue running the code below I use try catch. 
But when using **Serenity**, when there is a failure, it jumps to catch and continues the loop, but the following steps are **skipped**. I don't understand how this framework works yet. I have tried calling *ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.initialize();* again; But it still doesn't execute the steps. (It doesn't open the browser).

Can anyone help me? I want when it has a failure on any line of code, it must keep running again from the first step until the loop ends. It is not that it skips all steps. 
Thanks all!!! 
**Result:**

```
Start Try: 0

Catch: 0
Start Try: 1
End Try: 1
Start Try: 2
End Try: 2
Start Try: 3
End Try: 3
Start Try: 4
End Try: 4
18:07:20.542 [main] ERROR n.t.c.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener
```

Image report: 
[image: Report]

**Edit**
After 2 days I still could not find a way to initialize a new driver. But I have a way to fix my problem. 
That combines Scenario Outline, like this:

*Feature*

```
Scenario Outline: A scenario
    When Read excel "test.xlsx" by <index>
    Examples:
      | index |
      | 1     |
      | 2     |
      | 3     |
      |...    |
```

Edit code:

```
@When("Read excel {string} by {word}")
    public void readExcel(String fileName, String index) {
        Iterator<Row> iterator = getSheetExcel(fileName);
        List<Row> listRow = new ArrayList<>();
        int colName = 0;
        int colEmail = 1;
        // ....
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            listRow.add(iterator.next());
        }
        // example
        String name = listRow.get(Integer.parseInt(index)).getCell(colName).getStringCellValue();
        String email = listRow.get(Integer.parseInt(index)).getCell(colEmail).getStringCellValue();

        accessGoogle(name);
        inputSearch(email);
        inputSearch("stackoverflow.com");
        searchSucess();
    }

    public Iterator<Row> getSheetExcel(String fileName) {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/data/excel/" + fileName;
        File file = new File(path);   //creating a new file instance
        FileInputStream fis;          //obtaining bytes from the file
        XSSFWorkbook wb;              //creating Workbook instance that refers to .xlsx file
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);   //creating a Sheet object to retrieve object
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assert sheet != null;
        return sheet.iterator();
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reading data from tables usually is a use case for parameterized tests. With cucumber you need to put the data table into the feature file https://webkul.com/blog/parametrization-in-cucumber/

```
Scenario Outline: Test user Login with different credentials
    Given Open Firefox and navigate to Login page
    When valid "<username>" and "<password>" is entered
    Then User should be logged in successfully
 
Examples:
    | username   | password |
    | rahul@gmail.com | Test@123 |
    | xyz@gmail.com| Testtest |
```

see [Cucumber : How to read examples from external excel file for Scenarios Outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193890/cucumber-how-to-read-examples-from-external-excel-file-for-scenarios-outline) how to get the data from excel into the feature file.

It seems to me you are not very experienced with the frameworks you use, do you really need them? Maybe I can recommend starting with a simple JUnit Parameterized test? Example: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/junit-parameterized-test-selenium/

Comment: Thanks for supporting me. I know to use data table. With QAF, can you tell me how to integrate into my Serenity project?
My wish is to be able to read multiple records in excel. Each record is a repeat of the scenario time. It's like the function of Scenario Outline. Not just reading 1 record.