# How can I run my feature file multiple time based on the data i have on the excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, cucumber, bdd

I want to run the same scenario multiple times based on the number of rows in the excel sheet without repeat the row number in the feature file as shown below

I just want to initiate the first-row index 0 and make the code repeat the same scenario after the first execution based on numbers of rows in excel sheet

=========================Feature File===============================
Given navigate to Billing Account and serach with BillingNumber  and

When create request list with data in excel sheet  and

Then Validate status of MSISDN changed to Active

| sheetName | rowNumber |
| --- | --- |
| Sheet1 | 0 |
| Sheet1 | 1 |
| Sheet1 | 2 |

Comment: Why do you want to do that i.e. what is the purpose of reading it from Excel? Can't you just define the values as Scenario Outline (Examples) in your Feature file?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193890/cucumber-how-to-read-examples-from-external-excel-file-for-scenarios-outline